# How to draw distinct line segments in gnuplot using splot

Tags: gnuplot

I was under the impression that introducing an empty line between points creates disconnected plots.

If file Box.dat contains the following, I expect exactly two disconnected line segments to occur. However I get a square in the z plane. How do I get gnuplot to connect *only* the points not separated by a newline? For the following file I want gnuplot to generate 2 line segments:

```
Box.dat--------------------------
# Bounding box vertices
0 0 0 
1 0 0

0 0 1  
1 0 1
---------------------------------
 gnuplot> splot 'Box.dat'  using 1:2:3 with linespoints
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2D (using `plot`) it is true, that an empty line leads to disconnected line parts, see e.g.

```
set autoscale fix
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
plot 'Box.dat' using 1:3 w l
```

In 3D (with `splot`) a newline separates two lines of a surface. The same points of neighboring lines are then connected to form a surface. In order to get disconnected line segments in 3D you must use two newlines:

```
# Box.dat
0 0 0 
1 0 0


0 0 1  
1 0 1
```