# gnuplot: 3d polygons without connecting separate polygons

Tags: gnuplot

I have a list of 3d polygons which I want to plot.  I want to draw lines between the points of a given polygon, but not between the individual polygons.

I currently have

```
set parametric
unset hidden3d
unset key
set surface
set contour
set style data line
set xrange [-2:12]
set yrange [-2:12]
splot '-'
0.000 0.000 10.000
10.000 0.000 0.000
1.000 0.000 7.071
0.000 0.000 10.000

1.000 1.000 14.142
2.000 0.000 0.000
0.000 1.000 17.071
1.000 1.000 14.142

0.000 2.000 20.000
1.000 1.000 14.142
10.000 1.000 7.071
0.000 2.000 20.000
e
pause -1 "ENTER"
quit
```

But that includes lines between each polygon.  Is there a way to edit this script to get it so each polygon is internally connected, but not connected to any of the other polygons?

**edit**: I'd like it gnuplot 4.0 compatible; and I'd like to keep the contour if possible.

Comment: Use two empty lines between the polygons

Comment: That was easy, thanks.  If you change it to an answer, I'll accept it. :-)  (well, it doesn't allow me to have the contours, but I can live with that to be able to see the individual polygons)

Comment: I think we can close the question as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19928257/2604213