# gnuplot: How to draw disconnected lines with splot?

Tags: gnuplot

This is not a duplicate of [How to draw distinct line segments in gnuplot using splot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928257/how-to-draw-distinct-line-segments-in-gnuplot-using-splot) .
The question is slightly different, but I also would like to splot disconnected lines with `splot`. The link above says that you have to introduce 2 empty lines in your data. That's what I am doing when creating `$Data1`.

Question: Why is `$Data1` connected but `$Data2` disconnected? I want to have `$Data1` also disconnected. What's wrong? Any ideas? Bug or feature?

**Edit:**

@Ethan's answer basically leads to disconnected lines. But still, there is some inconsistency. When you create a datafile `Data3.dat`, it seems to be sufficient if you create it by just printing one `\n`, but in the file you see two `\n`. Why? I am confused.

Code:

```
### splot disconnected lines
reset session
set border 0
unset tics

set print $Data1
do for [i=1:3] {
    print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f",rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
    print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f",rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
    print "\n"; # print ""
}
set print

$Data2 <<EOD
0.266 0.838 0.173
0.413 0.985 0.102


0.173 0.879 0.478
0.375 0.748 0.659


0.605 0.365 0.966
0.001 0.426 0.129
EOD

FILE = "Data3.dat" 
set print FILE
do for [i=1:3] {
    print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f",rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
    print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f",rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
    print "\n"
}
set print


splot \
    $Data1 u 1:2:3 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" t "Why is $Data1 connected?", \
    $Data2 u 1:2:3 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "web-green" t "$Data2 disconnected", \
    FILE   u 1:2:3 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue" t 'Why is FILE with just one "\\n" disconnected'
### end of code
```

Result: `$Data1`

```
0.949 0.287 0.592
0.547 0.876 0.294


0.468 0.930 0.703
0.294 0.990 0.919


0.038 0.550 0.467
0.222 0.390 0.941
```

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating one blank line, not two, between data blocks in $data1

```
set print $Data1
do for [i=1:3] {
    print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f",rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
    print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.3f",rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
    print "\n"
    print "\n"   # 2 blank lines required
}
set print
```

Comment: but why is it displayed as two if I `print $Data1`?

Comment: well, I also tried `print "\n\n"` but it still is connected, although it shows 3 blank lines. Actually, `print ""; print ""` works. So, what is the difference?

Comment: The behavior of printing to a datablock has changed in the gnuplot development version.  In version 5.2  print "1\n2\n3\n" loads the entire string including embedded newlines into a single entry of the datablock.  In version 5.3 the same print statement expands the newlines to create three successive entries in the datablock.

Comment: [continued] You cannot tell the difference visually from a "print" statement, but there is one internally.  In either case when plotting from a datablock the program considers a "blank line" to be a datablock entry containing an empty string.   So in version 5.2 `print "\n\n"` to a data block produces only one "blank line", but in version 5.3 in produces two "blank lines". The development version behavior is not fixed in stone, so if you have opinions on this change please send them.

Comment: thank you for your explanations. If `print "\n\n"` generates two blank lines in a datablock this is what I expect. So, I will be fine with the development version. But the same command shouldn't create one or three or four, but also two `\n` if I print to a datafile.

Comment: hmmm.... I am still confused! How many blank lines would be generated by `print ""` and `print "\n"` and `print "\n\n"` in a datablock or in a datafile and in 5.2 or in 5.3, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Version 5.2.6

```
gnuplot> set print $D; print ""
gnuplot> set print $E; print "\n"
gnuplot> set print $F; print "\n\n"
gnuplot> set print $G; print "\n\nX"
gnuplot> show var $

        Variables beginning with $:
        $D = <1 line data block>
        $E = <1 line data block>
        $F = <1 line data block>
        $G = <1 line data block>
```

Version 5.3

```
gnuplot> set print $D; print ""
gnuplot> set print $E; print "\n"
gnuplot> set print $F; print "\n\n"
gnuplot> set print $G; print "\n\nX"
gnuplot> show var $

        Variables beginning with $:
        $D = <1 line data block>
        $E = <1 line data block>
        $F = <2 line data block>
        $G = <3 line data block>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is actually not about `splot`, but:
**How many blank lines do I get?**

To summarize what I've understood from @Ethan's comments and answers,

Some test code:

```
### How many empty lines do I get?
reset session

set print $Data1; print "1 Dataline"; print "";      print "2 Dataline";
set print $Data2; print "1 Dataline"; print "\n";    print "2 Dataline";
set print $Data3; print "1 Dataline"; print "\n\n";  print "2 Dataline";
set print $Data4; print "1 Dataline"; print "\n\nX"; print "2 Dataline";

set print "Data1.txt"; print "1 Dataline"; print "";      print "2 Dataline";
set print "Data2.txt"; print "1 Dataline"; print "\n";    print "2 Dataline";
set print "Data3.txt"; print "1 Dataline"; print "\n\n";  print "2 Dataline";
set print "Data4.txt"; print "1 Dataline"; print "\n\nX"; print "2 Dataline";
set print    

print $Data1
print $Data2
print $Data3
print $Data4
### end of code
```

Result:

```
A = print to a datablock (how gnuplot handles the datablock)
B = print datablock to gnuplot console (how gnuplot displays the datablock)
C = print to datafile

Blank lines:
                  5.2          5.3
               A   B   C    A   B   C    
print ""       1   1   1    1   1?  1?
print "\n"     1   2   2    1   1?  1?
print "\n\n"   1   3   3    2   2?  2?
print "\n\nX"  1   2   2    2   2?  2?
```

To my opinion columns A, B, C should be identical. Well, they are not in 5.2 (gnuplot internal acts differently than what you see), this was my actual "problem".
Since I do not have 5.3, I cannot test B and C, so these columns are just a guess, please correct them if I am wrong. To my opinion they should be identical to column A.